# How to show $\frac{n}{4}\ln [1+\int |\nabla \phi|^2 dV]\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int |\nabla \phi|^2 dV + C(g,n)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Picture below is from 90th page of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow. The integration is take on  closed smooth manifold.  I can't get the red line.

What I try:
$$
\frac{n}{4}\ln [1+\int |\nabla \phi|^2 dV]\le\frac{n}{4}\int |\nabla \phi|^2 dV
$$
then, I don't know how to get $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about $2\pi$. You can choose this constant as long as you make $C(g, n)$ large.

Since [$\ln(1+x)\le \sqrt{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162943/show-these-simple-inequalities-and-log1x2-le-x-and-that-log1x2?noredirect=1), together with $2ab \le \epsilon a^2 + \epsilon ^{-1} b^2$, we have

$$ \frac n4 \ln (1+x) \le \frac n4 \sqrt x \le \frac  n4 ( \epsilon x + \epsilon^{-1}) = \frac{n\epsilon}{4} x + \frac{n}{4\epsilon}. $$

Now choose $\epsilon$ so that $\frac{n\epsilon}{4} = \frac{1}{2\pi}$ and $x = \int _M |\nabla \phi|^2 dV$, one obtain your inequality (with a different $C(g, n)$, as suggested in the text).